# how to make this as scrolling animation faster on touch devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

On scroll up, I move the input-field down as the user scrolls and moves it up as the user scrolls down.

I like how this is behaving on desktop, but in multi-touch / mobile devices, it takes way too long of a scroll (distance) to get the `#searchInput` down into view.

On mobile multi-touch, how can I get the input-field to come down on scroll up easier / with less of a scroll distance ?

Here is a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Fc6PU/3/

Here is the code:

```
var scrollTop = 0;
var upDistance = 0;
var downDistance = 0;
var written = false;
var searchTop = 0;
$(window).on('scroll', function(){
    if($(window).scrollTop()<scrollTop){
        $('#searchInput').removeClass('initialTop').addClass('slideBack');
    written = false;
    downDistance = 0;
    upDistance++;
        $('#searchInput').css('top', -21+upDistance);
    }
else{
    upDistance = 0;
    downDistance++;
    if(!written){
        searchTop = parseInt($('#searchInput').css('top'));
        written = true;
    }
        $('#searchInput').css('top', searchTop-downDistance);
    }
    scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
});
```

Comment: use 'scrollstart' instead of 'scroll' for touch device example http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/jquerymobile_events_scroll.asp

Comment: @Koushik nope, that didn't make a difference.